# Equal sized columns when Grid aligns to the right

Tags: wpf

I'm creating a Dialog in WPF with pretty standard Save and Cancel buttons. I want the Save and Cancel buttons to have the same width. I thought this would be a trivial matter. I placed the buttons in a Grid, with two columns sized to '*', yet the columns have different widths!!

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Save" Margin="8" />
    <Button Content="Cancel" Margin="8" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

**If I take off the Horizontal alignment, the columns size equally**, but the Grid is too large. How do I get a Grid, aligned right, with two equal columns??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
  <UniformGrid  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Columns="2">

        <Button Content="Save" Margin="8" />
        <Button Content="Cancel" Margin="8" Grid.Column="1" />
    </UniformGrid>
```